# Append multiple values in a array

Tags: python, hubspot, hubspot-crm

'I am trying to fetch deals data from Hubspot, I am trying to fetch dealid and deal name in this example to simplify the question but later I will more properties. I have the following code that gives me an array of dealIds and one array of deal names. I could I make it that instead of multiple arrays I get the following instead:

`{{12345,'deal1'}, {12346,'deal2'}, {12347,'deal3'}}`

or something like:

`{{'dealId': 12345, 'dealname' : 'deal1'}}`

This is my code so far:

```
deals = []
names = []

def getdeals():
    apikey = "demo"
    url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/paged?hapikey='+apikey+'&properties=dealname&limit=250'
    response = requests.get(url)
    jsonDeals = response.json()

    for deal in jsonDeals['deals']:
       properties = deal['properties']
       deals.append(deal['dealId'])
       names.append(properties['dealname']['value'])
```

Comment: you already have those things in the json you are getting back. If you want dealname deal id just do deal_obj = {'dealname': properties['dealname']['value'], 'dealid':deal['dealId']}. But I don't see the opoint

Comment: What does the `jsonDeals` look like? Should be worth adding them to the description so we can have a better idea of how we can help format the JSON response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the data in json. Its just how you want to map and store it.

```
output={}
def getdeals():
    apikey = "demo"
    url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/paged?hapikey='+apikey+'&properties=dealname&limit=250'
    response = requests.get(url)
    jsonDeals = response.json()

    for deal in jsonDeals['deals']:
       properties = deal['properties']
       output.update({deal['dealId']: properties['dealname']['value']})
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using list comprehension:

```
[{'dealId':deal['dealId'],'dealname':deal['properties']['dealname']['value']} for deal in jsonDeals['deals']]
```

Answer (score 0):

AS E.Serra suggested deal_obj = {'dealname': properties['dealname']['value'], 'dealid':deal['dealId']} solved the issue.

here is the updated code:

```
%%time
deals = []

def getdeals():
    apikey = "demo"
    url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/deals/v1/deal/paged?hapikey='+apikey+'&properties=dealname&limit=250'
    response = requests.get(url)
    jsonDeals = response.json()

    for deal in jsonDeals['deals']:
       properties = deal['properties']
       deal_obj = {'dealname': properties['dealname']['value'], 'dealid':deal['dealId']}
       deals.append(deal_obj)
```